# Difficulty in openning a file

Tags: python, numpy

Instead of saving the goog.npz file in the directory suggested below, I would like to save it here:

file_path = 'C:/Users/.../goog.npz'

and then substitute r (below) to something that reads the file in the position stored.  Thanks for the help!

```
# Load a numpy record array from yahoo csv data with fields date, open, close,
# volume, adj_close from the mpl-data/example directory. The record array
# stores the date as an np.datetime64 with a day unit ('D') in the date column.

with cbook.get_sample_data('goog.npz') as datafile:
    r = np.load(datafile)['price_data'].view(np.recarray)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify the whole path for the file in the `get_sample_data` method:

```
with cbook.get_sample_data('C:Users/.../goog.npz') as datafile:
    r = np.load(datafile)['price_data'].view(np.recarray)
```

Comment: Perfect, ruohola. Thanks a lot!  Regards, fskilnik.